# MigPane compatibility with FXML and Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, fxml, miglayout, scenebuilder

Before I jump on the MigPane bandwagon I would like to know:

1. Is it possible to specify MidPane layouts in a .fxml file?
2. If so: can someone point me to some examples?
3. Is it possible to use Scene Builder 2.0 to edit a .fxml file containing MidPane's?
4. If so: what magic lines do I have to add to the .fxml?

I have been unable to find answers, only hint is [this example](https://github.com/zonski/hello-javafx-maven-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/fxml/hello.fxml) (so (1) should be a "yes").

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 questions for the price of one:

**1. Yes**

As you even pointed it out, it is possible as long as you keep all the dependencies i.e
import this of FXML:

```
<?import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane?>
<?import layouttests.migfxml.sample1.*?>
```

And the [MigLayout](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/versions/4.0/) and the [MigPane](https://java.net/projects/miglayoutfx2/downloads) on your project.

**2.** Despite of your [own example](https://github.com/zonski/hello-javafx-maven-example), you should focus on [actual code](http://robmayhew.com/javafx-2-0-layout-with-migpane/). Please, do try both and compile/run them. I.e have fun with it until you understand it more.

**3. No.** But SceneBuilder doesn't support even some actual JavaFX features such as including items in a ComboBox so this is not surprising (it will tell you that the fxml is invalid). But **don't be afraid/scared** of editing directly the `FXML` it's essentially xml with some javaFX specific features.

**4.** *Look at the answer for the question number 1*

Comment: I managed to use MigPane in fxml (ditching SceneBuilder), but I still have a couple of questions: is there a way to define Layout/Row/Column constrints? Perusal of code would suggest a "no"; How complete and stable is the interface? I found no way to activate scrollbars.

Comment: This question (and answer) is 2 years old now.  Have there been updates?  I have to observe that making a "gui editor" that  will not let me integrate new widgets/components is a kind of _terminal illness_ in this day and age.

Answer (score 0):

MiGLayout supports all those constraints you're trying to instantiate, just read the http://www.miglayout.com/cheatsheet.html cheat sheet.